# Partial R-squared value for random effects in a mixed effects (or multi-level) model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

A number of tools now use [Nakagawa and Schielzeth's (2012)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract) method for obtaining R-squared values for mixed effects (or multi-level) models (i.e., the [MuMIN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MuMIn) R package).

The [r2glmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/r2glmm/index.html) R package provides for the calculation of semi-partial R-squared values for specific fixed effects predictors.

Are there similar, partial R-squared values for specific random effects? E.g., for a model with two random effects, can semi-partial R-squared values for each random effect be calculated (can they simply be the square of the intra-class correlation)?